# How can I decrypt the js codes?

Tags: javascript

I need to decrypt the js code and then I can figure out if the js code has some defeats.

Sample：

```
    var script = document[__Ox26de9[0x1]](__Ox26de9[0x0]);
    script[__Ox26de9[0x2]] = __Ox26de9[0x3];
    script[__Ox26de9[0x4]] = __Ox26de9[0x5];
    document[__Ox26de9[0x7]][__Ox26de9[0x6]](script);
```

var __Ox26de9 = ["\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x73\x72\x63", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x2E\x73\x69\x6E\x61\x61\x70\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D", "\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64", "\x68\x65\x61\x64", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x54\x79\x70\x65", "\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73", "\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65", "\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64", "\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6D\x6F\x7A\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6D\x73\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6F\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x77\x65\x62\x6B\x69\x74\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x65\x78\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x73", "\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x79", "\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x67\x61\x74\x65\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x63\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x2E\x2F\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x73\x74", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74", "\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x5D", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5D", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x66\x6E", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x46\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5D", "\x4D\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x72\x65\x71\x75\x69\x72\x65\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73", "\x53\x65\x63\x6F\x6E\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x54\x68\x69\x72\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x46\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x46\x69\x72\x73\x74\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x2C\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x2C\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2C\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74", "\x66\x6F\x72\x45\x61\x63\x68", "\x62\x6F\x64\x79", "\x2E\x2F\x69\x73", "\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x67\x61\x74\x65", "\x53\x45\x4C\x45\x43\x54", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73", "\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65", "\x49\x4E\x50\x55\x54", "\x54\x45\x58\x54\x41\x52\x45\x41", "\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79", "\x68\x61\x73\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "", "\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74", "\x73\x65\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x64\x69\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x67\x65\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x73", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x6C\x6C\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x73", "\x61\x64\x64\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x65", "\x70\x75\x73\x68", "\x6F\x66\x66", "\x5F", "\x6F\x6E", "\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65", "\x63\x74\x78", "\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74", "\x5F\x5F\x65\x73\x4D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65", "\x43\x61\x6E\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x20\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x20\x61\x73\x20\x61\x20\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x73\x79\x6D\x62\x6F\x6C", "\x69\x74\x65\x72\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x65\x6E\x75\x6D\x65\x72\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x66\x69\x67\x75\x72\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x77\x72\x69\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x6B\x65\x79", "\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79", "\x72\x65\x73\x6F\x6C\x76\x65\x4F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73", "\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72", "\x65\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x74\x65\x78\x74", "\x74\x72\x69\x67\x67\x65\x72", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x46\x61\x6B\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x72\x74\x6C", "\x64\x69\x72", "\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x46\x61\x6B\x65", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x48\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x72\x43\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x48\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x61\x72\x65\x61", "\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x53\x69\x7A\x65", "\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65", "\x31\x32\x70\x74", "\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72", "\x30", "\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67", "\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E", "\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65", "\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78", "\x70\x61\x67\x65\x59\x4F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74", "\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70", "\x74\x6F\x70", "\x70\x78", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74", "\x63\x6F\x70\x79\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64", "\x65\x78\x65\x63\x43\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64", "\x68\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x52\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74", "\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73", "\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72", "\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x65\x6D\x69\x74", "\x64\x65\x73\x74\x72\x6F\x79", "\x63\x6F\x70\x79", "\x5F\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x75\x74", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x22\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x22\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x2C\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x65\x69\x74\x68\x65\x72\x20\x22\x63\x6F\x70\x79\x22\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x22\x63\x75\x74\x22", "\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x22\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x22\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x2C\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x61\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x22\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x22\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x2E\x20\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x22\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79\x22\x20\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x65\x61\x64\x20\x6F\x66\x20\x22\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64\x22\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x22\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x22\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x2E\x20\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x63\x61\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x63\x75\x74\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x20\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x65\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x20\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20\x22\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79\x22\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x22\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64\x22\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x73", "\x5F\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x61\x6D\x64", "\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65", "\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x41\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x68\x61\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x62\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x69\x61\x6C\x69\x73\x65\x64\x20\x2D\x20\x73\x75\x70\x65\x72\x28\x29\x20\x68\x61\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x62\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x65\x64", "\x53\x75\x70\x65\x72\x20\x65\x78\x70\x72\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x65\x69\x74\x68\x65\x72\x20\x62\x65\x20\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x61\x20\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2C\x20\x6E\x6F\x74\x20", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65", "\x73\x65\x74\x50\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x4F\x66", "\x5F\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x5F\x5F", "\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x2D", "\x67\x65\x74\x50\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x4F\x66", "\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x41\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x6F\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x63\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x69\x73\x53\x75\x70\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x65\x64", "\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x43\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64\x53\x75\x70\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x65\x64", "\x2E\x2F\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x2D\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x74\x69\x6E\x79\x2D\x65\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x67\x6F\x6F\x64\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x74\x69\x6E\x79\x45\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x67\x6F\x6F\x64\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64", "\x43\x61\x6E\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x20\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65\x20\x27", "\x27", "\x63\x6F\x64\x65", "\x4D\x4F\x44\x55\x4C\x45\x5F\x4E\x4F\x54\x5F\x46\x4F\x55\x4E\x44", "\x43\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64", "\x73\x68\x6F\x77", "\x23\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x2E\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x2E\x62\x74\x6E", "\u590D\u5236\u6210\u529F\x21\u5373\u5C06\u6253\u5F00\u5FAE\u4FE1", "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x77\x65\x69\x78\x69\x6E\x3A\x2F\x2F", "\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"];
Thanks a lot

Comment: If you mean defects, you should check your original source code. Not the obfuscated one.

Comment: So do you have variable named `__Ox26de9`?

Comment: If you do not have the original source code, see [Reverse Engineering Stack Exchange](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/q/4561) instead.

Comment: @Justinas  I post it to the description, but it is too complex...

Comment: @WadeChen try the answer below.

Answer (score -1):

Go to [this link](http://ddecode.com/hexdecoder/?results=b60b6c12a36a0f109e9c25d940bc51ab)
Here I've decoded the above code from hex and now you can find out and fix what's the issue.

As I've found out that the double quotes inside a string which is enclosed in double quotes are not escaped. Either use the escape character or use single quotes.

Here I've replaced double quotes to single. Now it'll work fine. Give it a try.

```
var __Ox26de9 = ["\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x2F\x6A\x61\x76\x61\x73\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74", "\x73\x72\x63", "\x68\x74\x74\x70\x3A\x2F\x2F\x63\x73\x73\x2E\x73\x69\x6E\x61\x61\x70\x6B\x2E\x63\x6F\x6D", "\x61\x70\x70\x65\x6E\x64\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64", "\x68\x65\x61\x64", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x54\x79\x70\x65", "\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73", "\x70\x61\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65", "\x75\x6E\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x64", "\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65", "\x6D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6D\x6F\x7A\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6D\x73\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x6F\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x77\x65\x62\x6B\x69\x74\x4D\x61\x74\x63\x68\x65\x73\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x65\x78\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x73", "\x61\x70\x70\x6C\x79", "\x61\x64\x64\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x45\x76\x65\x6E\x74\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x67\x61\x74\x65\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x63\x61\x6C\x6C", "\x2E\x2F\x63\x6C\x6F\x73\x65\x73\x74", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74", "\x74\x6F\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x5D", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5D", "\x6C\x65\x6E\x67\x74\x68", "\x73\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x66\x6E", "\x5B\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74\x20\x46\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x5D", "\x4D\x69\x73\x73\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x72\x65\x71\x75\x69\x72\x65\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73", "\x53\x65\x63\x6F\x6E\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67", "\x54\x68\x69\x72\x64\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x46\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x46\x69\x72\x73\x74\x20\x61\x72\x67\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x62\x65\x20\x61\x20\x53\x74\x72\x69\x6E\x67\x2C\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x2C\x20\x48\x54\x4D\x4C\x43\x6F\x6C\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2C\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x4C\x69\x73\x74", "\x66\x6F\x72\x45\x61\x63\x68", "\x62\x6F\x64\x79", "\x2E\x2F\x69\x73", "\x64\x65\x6C\x65\x67\x61\x74\x65", "\x53\x45\x4C\x45\x43\x54", "\x6E\x6F\x64\x65\x4E\x61\x6D\x65", "\x66\x6F\x63\x75\x73", "\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65", "\x49\x4E\x50\x55\x54", "\x54\x45\x58\x54\x41\x52\x45\x41", "\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79", "\x68\x61\x73\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "", "\x73\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74", "\x73\x65\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x65\x64\x69\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x67\x65\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x4E\x6F\x64\x65\x43\x6F\x6E\x74\x65\x6E\x74\x73", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x41\x6C\x6C\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65\x73", "\x61\x64\x64\x52\x61\x6E\x67\x65", "\x65", "\x70\x75\x73\x68", "\x6F\x66\x66", "\x5F", "\x6F\x6E", "\x73\x6C\x69\x63\x65", "\x63\x74\x78", "\x75\x73\x65\x20\x73\x74\x72\x69\x63\x74", "\x5F\x5F\x65\x73\x4D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65", "\x43\x61\x6E\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x20\x61\x20\x63\x6C\x61\x73\x73\x20\x61\x73\x20\x61\x20\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x73\x79\x6D\x62\x6F\x6C", "\x69\x74\x65\x72\x61\x74\x6F\x72", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x73\x74\x72\x75\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x65\x6E\x75\x6D\x65\x72\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x66\x69\x67\x75\x72\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x77\x72\x69\x74\x61\x62\x6C\x65", "\x6B\x65\x79", "\x64\x65\x66\x69\x6E\x65\x50\x72\x6F\x70\x65\x72\x74\x79", "\x72\x65\x73\x6F\x6C\x76\x65\x4F\x70\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x73", "\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x6F\x6E\x74\x61\x69\x6E\x65\x72", "\x65\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x74\x65\x78\x74", "\x74\x72\x69\x67\x67\x65\x72", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x65\x64\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x46\x61\x6B\x65", "\x73\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x72\x74\x6C", "\x64\x69\x72", "\x67\x65\x74\x41\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x64\x6F\x63\x75\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x46\x61\x6B\x65", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x48\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x72\x43\x61\x6C\x6C\x62\x61\x63\x6B", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x48\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x66\x61\x6B\x65\x45\x6C\x65\x6D", "\x74\x65\x78\x74\x61\x72\x65\x61", "\x66\x6F\x6E\x74\x53\x69\x7A\x65", "\x73\x74\x79\x6C\x65", "\x31\x32\x70\x74", "\x62\x6F\x72\x64\x65\x72", "\x30", "\x70\x61\x64\x64\x69\x6E\x67", "\x6D\x61\x72\x67\x69\x6E", "\x70\x6F\x73\x69\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x61\x62\x73\x6F\x6C\x75\x74\x65", "\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x6C\x65\x66\x74", "\x2D\x39\x39\x39\x39\x70\x78", "\x70\x61\x67\x65\x59\x4F\x66\x66\x73\x65\x74", "\x73\x63\x72\x6F\x6C\x6C\x54\x6F\x70", "\x74\x6F\x70", "\x70\x78", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74", "\x63\x6F\x70\x79\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x72\x65\x6D\x6F\x76\x65\x43\x68\x69\x6C\x64", "\x65\x78\x65\x63\x43\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64", "\x68\x61\x6E\x64\x6C\x65\x52\x65\x73\x75\x6C\x74", "\x73\x75\x63\x63\x65\x73\x73", "\x65\x72\x72\x6F\x72", "\x62\x69\x6E\x64", "\x63\x6C\x65\x61\x72\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x65\x6D\x69\x74", "\x64\x65\x73\x74\x72\x6F\x79", "\x63\x6F\x70\x79", "\x5F\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x63\x75\x74", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x27\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x27\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x2C\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x65\x69\x74\x68\x65\x72\x20\x27\x63\x6F\x70\x79\x27\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x27\x63\x75\x74\x27", "\x6F\x62\x6A\x65\x63\x74", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x27\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x27\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x75\x65\x2C\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x61\x20\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x45\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74", "\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x27\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x27\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x2E\x20\x50\x6C\x65\x61\x73\x65\x20\x75\x73\x65\x20\x27\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79\x27\x20\x69\x6E\x73\x74\x65\x61\x64\x20\x6F\x66\x20\x27\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64\x27\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65", "\x49\x6E\x76\x61\x6C\x69\x64\x20\x27\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74\x27\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x2E\x20\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x63\x61\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x63\x75\x74\x20\x74\x65\x78\x74\x20\x66\x72\x6F\x6D\x20\x65\x6C\x65\x6D\x65\x6E\x74\x73\x20\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20\x27\x72\x65\x61\x64\x6F\x6E\x6C\x79\x27\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x27\x64\x69\x73\x61\x62\x6C\x65\x64\x27\x20\x61\x74\x74\x72\x69\x62\x75\x74\x65\x73", "\x5F\x74\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x61\x6D\x64", "\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65", "\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x41\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x74\x68\x69\x73\x20\x68\x61\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x62\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x69\x6E\x69\x74\x69\x61\x6C\x69\x73\x65\x64\x20\x2D\x20\x73\x75\x70\x65\x72\x28\x29\x20\x68\x61\x73\x6E\x27\x74\x20\x62\x65\x65\x6E\x20\x63\x61\x6C\x6C\x65\x64", "\x53\x75\x70\x65\x72\x20\x65\x78\x70\x72\x65\x73\x73\x69\x6F\x6E\x20\x6D\x75\x73\x74\x20\x65\x69\x74\x68\x65\x72\x20\x62\x65\x20\x6E\x75\x6C\x6C\x20\x6F\x72\x20\x61\x20\x66\x75\x6E\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E\x2C\x20\x6E\x6F\x74\x20", "\x63\x72\x65\x61\x74\x65", "\x73\x65\x74\x50\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x4F\x66", "\x5F\x5F\x70\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x5F\x5F", "\x64\x61\x74\x61\x2D\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x2D", "\x67\x65\x74\x50\x72\x6F\x74\x6F\x74\x79\x70\x65\x4F\x66", "\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x41\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x64\x65\x66\x61\x75\x6C\x74\x54\x65\x78\x74", "\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x6F\x6E\x43\x6C\x69\x63\x6B", "\x63\x75\x72\x72\x65\x6E\x74\x54\x61\x72\x67\x65\x74", "\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x53\x65\x6C\x65\x63\x74\x6F\x72", "\x69\x73\x53\x75\x70\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x65\x64", "\x71\x75\x65\x72\x79\x43\x6F\x6D\x6D\x61\x6E\x64\x53\x75\x70\x70\x6F\x72\x74\x65\x64", "\x2E\x2F\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64\x2D\x61\x63\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x74\x69\x6E\x79\x2D\x65\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x67\x6F\x6F\x64\x2D\x6C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x74\x69\x6E\x79\x45\x6D\x69\x74\x74\x65\x72", "\x67\x6F\x6F\x64\x4C\x69\x73\x74\x65\x6E\x65\x72", "\x63\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64", "\x43\x61\x6E\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x66\x69\x6E\x64\x20\x6D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65\x20\x27", "\x27", "\x63\x6F\x64\x65", "\x4D\x4F\x44\x55\x4C\x45\x5F\x4E\x4F\x54\x5F\x46\x4F\x55\x4E\x44", "\x43\x6C\x69\x70\x62\x6F\x61\x72\x64", "\x73\x68\x6F\x77", "\x23\x73\x68\x61\x64\x6F\x77\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x2E\x72\x69\x67\x68\x74", "\x68\x69\x64\x65", "\x2E\x62\x74\x6E", "\u590D\u5236\u6210\u529F\x21\u5373\u5C06\u6253\u5F00\u5FAE\u4FE1", "\x6C\x6F\x63\x61\x74\x69\x6F\x6E", "\x77\x65\x69\x78\x69\x6E\x3A\x2F\x2F", "\x72\x65\x61\x64\x79"];
```